# Browser ignoring stylesheet from extension

Tags: html, css, input, google-chrome-extension

I have an chrome extension. I need to style some `<input>` in `<div id="panel">` using css.
In my extension, I am applying following style:

```
#panel input[type="text"] {
    border: 1px solid var(--gray-color) !important;
}
```

But this change is in chrome ignored and in inspector there is only empty selector without border style.

```
#panel input[type="text"] {                                                injected stylesheet
}
```

I'm not able to add this border style to the element.

Comment: Did you reload the extension on chrome://extensions page and the tab itself?

Comment: Yes, I even tried to remove the extension and upload it again. Didn't fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the `var(--gray-color)` and added classic HEX color e.g. #cccccc.

Comment: it would have been useful perhaps to see exactly how that was declared within the CSS, and perhaps (it it is/was NOT set or improperly so, to use a default `var(--gray-color, #CCCCCC)` value in there

Comment: The variable has been declared
:root {
  --gray-color: #cccccc;
}

Answer (score 0):

You have something else wrong in your CSS or markup. Here are some examples of "wrong" but might not be your "wrong"

```css
:root {
  --gray-color: #cccccc;
  --cool-color: #22ccCC;
  --my-cool-color: var(--cool-coler, #ff0000);
}

#panel input {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
/* works */
#panel input[type="text"] {
  border: 1px solid var(--gray-color);
}

/* use second due to spelling error */
#panel input[type="text"].tester {
  border: 4px solid var(--grey-color, #0000ff);
}

/* uses the first no spelling error */
#panel input.styler {
  border: 3px solid var(--gray-color, #ffddff);
}

/* uses the second in def spelling error in def */
#panel input.cooler {
  border: 2px solid var(--my-cool-color, #ffddff);
}
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  Border this: <input type="text" />
  <br /> Border this: <input class="tester" type="text" />
  <br /> Not this: <input class='styler' />
  <br />cooler This: <input class='cooler' />
</div>
```

Comment: I added this as an answer  instead of extended notes but voted to close since the question does not reproduce the error.